# What mechanisms might make a substance travel different distances on the same TLC plate?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, chromatography

When doing TLCs to monitor reactions, it is considered good common practice to not only spot the reactants and the reaction mixture (likely after some mini-workup), but also to include a ‘cross-spot’: every other substance (mixture) spotted somewhere on the plate is spotted together on one spot, commonly labelled something like *X*.

When asking why during my bachelor's thesis, the PhD student supervising me said something that roughly translates to:

> You can't be sure that the components don't run differently in the mixture than by themselves.

But in a perfect world, they should. Aside from the obvious case of having a polar reaction solvent that didn't entirely evaporate and skewes the elution mixture on parts of the TLC, are there other reasons why the components of a mixture should have different R<sub>f</sub> values when spotted separately?

Comment: I think you have the key point there about the reaction solvent affecting the Rf of your analyte. Using a mini-workup routinely is a good habit to get into. In my experience, the cross spot is primarily useful to distinguish compounds that are very close in polarity.

Answer (score 2):

> are there other reasons why the components of a mixture should have different Rf values when spotted separately?

One might speculate that two polar reactants form a less polar "adduct". This should however result in an additional spot, rather than in altered $\mathrm{R_f}$ values for the individual compounds.

But this is speculation. Admittedly, I have never used the *cross* spot method. Neither have I ever observed that spots of the reactants had different $\mathrm{R_f}$ values in the reaction mixture.

On a side note: What always worked for me was:

- Don't apply spots but bands and overlap them.
- "Sharpen" the bands on the base line by developping the TLC in methanol or another polar solvent first.

Together, these two tricks allow to destinguish between two compounds with very similar  $\mathrm{R_f}$ values.